# "AuthorizationFailed" when requesting Azure metrics data

Tags: azure, ionic-framework, active-directory, metrics

I'm trying to access metrics data in my localhost (http://localhost:8100) Ionic webapp of my resources using the Active Directory App Registration.
My administrator created a new app registration for my localhost app make it possible to request a new Bearer accesstoken.
After receiving the accesstoken I would like to let the application use this accesstoken to request metrics data.
One of the urls my webapp uses to call metrics (http GET request) is:

`"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroup_name}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{VirtualMachine_name}/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?api-version=2018-01-01&metricnames=Percentage%20CPU&timespan=2018-10-16T03:00:00Z/2018-10-17T03:00:00Z"` 
 with headers: 
`Authorization: {Bearer access_token},`
`Content-Type: 'application/json'`

Unfortunately, after sending this get request it returns the error `"AuthorizationFailed"` (http error code 403) with message: 
 `"The client '{client id}' with object id '{same as client id}' does not have authorization to perform action 'microsoft.Insights/metrics/read' over scope '/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourceGroups/{resourcegroup_name}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{VirtualMachine_name}/providers/microsoft.Insights'."`

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Your admin needs to assign a role to the app on the subscription/resource group/resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue since I noticed that the registered app in Active Directory has no granted roles. 
 I granted a role to this application by navigating to the `subscription` window and then to the `Access control (IAM)` tab. In this tab, I added the application which was declared in Active Directory Application Registrations and granted the role `reader`. 
Since I saved the settings, the `AuthorizationFailed` error hasn't occured anymore.